# How to add value in href from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i'm trying to create table from JSON.
I need to add a value from JSON in  tag

```
function drawProjectRow(rowProject) {
    var row = $("<tr/>")
    $("#projectListTable").append(row);
    row.append($("<td><a href = MY URL PLUS VALUE from rowProject.key> " + rowProject.key + "</a></td>"));
}
```

Comment: You could do it the same way you add the `rowProject.key` value: Use string concatenation.

Comment: `<td><a href = MY URL PLUS VALUE from ${rowProject.key} >${rowProject.key}</a></td>`;
do like this

Comment: @FelixKling This solution not working, getting URL without value. 

   row.append($("<td class=\"confluenceTd\" ><a href = \'example.com\"+rowProject.key+\"\'>" + rowProject.key + "</a></td>")); 

such a link is obtained in the table -  example.com" + rowProject.key + "

Comment: That's because you are forgot to add a `"` before the first and after the second `+`. You are not performing string concatenation, `+ rowProject.key+` is part of the string value in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see the value is being rendered ,

```js
var rowProject=2;
console.log("<td><a href ='MY URL"+rowProject+"'> " + rowProject + "</a></td>")
```

You can do that

```
 row.append("<td><a href ='MY URL"+rowProject.key+"'> " + rowProject.key + "</a></td>");
```

Or you can follow template literals

Comment: row.append($("<td class=\"confluenceTd\" ><a href = \'http://example.com/\"+rowProject.key+\"\'>" + rowProject.key + "</a></td>"));

getting URL  http://example.com/" + rowProject.key + " without value, but in table getting key.

Comment: why you are using $ inside append?

Comment: Good question)
Without $ inside append still working, ty!
But I need getting url with value from JSON.

Comment: I have edited my answere , with snippet there you can see its working

Comment: Yes it works I got confused in quotes  

row.append(("<td ><a href = URL" + rowProject.key + ">" +  rowProject.key + "</a></td>"));

Answer (score 0):

Coolest way to handle this in JavaScript

```
"<td><a href = MY URL PLUS VALUE from rowProject.key> " + rowProject.key + "</a></td>"
```

to

```
`<td><a href="${rowProject.key}">${rowProject.key}</a></td>`;
```

Comment: I need solution on jquery

Comment: @Direk: String manipulation/building has nothing to do with jQuery. The way you are currently building the HTML string also doesn't "use" jQuery.